# Unexpected behavior for drawOval

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I'm facing problem with drawOval function. I use it to draw circle but the result doesn't look like a circle. 
I think this behavior happened after certain height for Jpanel.
Scroll down till the end and you can get the result as shown in the attached image below.
Could anyone offer an explanation for this?

[Result after Execute the sample program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acaAm.png)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
        jsp.setViewportView(new TestPanel());
        f.getContentPane().add(jsp);
        f.setSize(500,400);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TestPanel extends JPanel
{
    public TestPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1960 , 77660240));
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawRect(30, 77660141, 100, 20);
        g2.drawOval(15, 77660141, 10, 10);
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(140, 77660141,
                             10,
                             10));
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(160, 77660141,
                             10,
                             10));
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(180, 77660141,
                             10,
                             10));
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 77660141,
                             30,
                             30));
    }
}
```

Comment: `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1960 , 77660240));` ..and what did you expect to happen with the 77660240 number? That is over 70 **thousand** times taller then my current screen!

Comment: then what is the benefit on using JScrollPane??

Comment: Scroll panes were meant to account for components that are larger than the available displayable space. But not those components that are **ridiculously** larger than the available space. Think of the slider bar thing for instance. It scales so that longer objects will produce a smaller slider. But at a 70,000 times difference, the slider would 'logically' be .. a fraction of a pixel tall! There is also the question of whether the JRE has enough memory available to handle such large objects. If I knew the ultimate purpose if this, I might be able to suggest better strategies.

Comment: Oddly, for me the deformations start to appear at about `(2^31-1)/64`. Not sure if it means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dimension of the panel to something more reasonable, ex.: 1000 and it will work correctly.

Comment: But why it works correctly for drawRect and there is no restriction on the size.

Comment: Don't know why but such a size is absolutely unreasonable for sure. I tried with 7000000 and it works, but even that size is not realistic...